# CSS, Textareas and iframes - height %s

Tags: html, css, iframe, textarea

I currently have a wrapper div that has two children: div left and div right. In div left, I have a textarea; in div right I have an iframe.

I'd like both children to have 80% height. Here are the relevant tags I'm using:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}

iframe {
    height: 80%;
}

textarea {
    height: 80%;
}
```

The iframe goes 80% of the entire page width, as I'd expect, but the textarea doesn't go all the way to 80% of the page. I've found that it goes 80% of div left's height, and setting div.left height to 100% doesn't make textarea take up all the space it needs to.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Because a height property usually grow up with the contents. So you can use javascript to calculate the exact height and set the textarea to be that many pixels.